# Put two outside divs above center div on smaller screen

Tags: html, css

The subject says it all, but I am looking for a clean simple way to do this. Essentially think of it like this:

[A][__B_][A]

to

[A][A]

[__B_]

Hopefully that is clear enough but I can elaborate if need be.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How wide should B be, is it 100%?

Comment: Do you have any code? Please post what you have already tried.

Answer (score 2):

you can use flexbox order for that

```css
.flex-container {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-item {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background: green;
 padding: 20px;
 width: 20%;
 height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid white;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
 .flex-item {
  background: green;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
 }
 .flex-item:nth-of-type(2) {
  order: 3;
  width: 100%
 }

}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">div a</div>
  <div class="flex-item">div b</div>
  <div class="flex-item">div a</div>
</div>
```

read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/order

Answer (score -1):

If you're starting with 3 elements in a row together, but you need element B to be outside on it's own, you will want to utilize [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

You'd be focusing on the `order` property for the selectors, and using `flex-grow` on element B. Read through that document to get an idea on how to set that up, or to make sure that's exactly what you need. Otherwise, you can turn to `jQuery`.

Comment: Flexbox is not supported in all browser, and it is not an easy solution as how OP asked for.

Comment: Flexbox is an easy solution and is widely supported with a lot of backups to it.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this by putting all three divs inside one div:

```
<div class="allthree">
    <div class="twoas">
        <div class="a"></div>
        <div class="a"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="oneb">
        <div class="b"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now add some CSS to this so the b is 100% width and the a is 50% width. Make sure the a is `display: inline-block;`

```
.allthree {
    width: <your-width>
}

.allthree .twoas {
    width: 100%;
} 

.allthree .twoas .a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}

.allthree .oneb {
    width: 100%;
} 

.allthree .oneb .b {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: How does this resolve the issue if it's going from a 3 item row down? Unless I am misunderstanding the OP.

Comment: I am putting everything inside a div. The two that should be next to eachother as well. It is easier to construct like that. You are using flexbox which is not supported in all browsers.

Comment: Ran your code, it doesn't do what the OP asked for. Flexbox would resolve this issue and is very easy to add. You'd only need to use order.

Comment: You're fundamentally changing the ordering. The whole point of the question is that the order A,B,C must be maintained, but B must be shown below A,C on a small screen.